# sqlite3 query return field from table1 based on information from table2

Tags: sql, sqlite

Product: Sqlite 3

I am very, very new to SQL.  At this time, I do not know how to ask the question properly.

I have two tables, tableA and tableB.

TableA has the following relevant columns:

```
| itemID | itemName |
```

TableB has the following relevant columns:

```
| typeID |
```

I want to do a query that will return  `itemName` for each `typeID`

Based on my very limited knowledge and searching, I've started looking into SQL JOIN type statements, but I'm having difficulty figuring it out.

Any advice or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your data description appear to be missing the mapping between item and type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have common values in `itemID` and `typeID` then probably You can join on them like

```
select t1.itemName 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.itemID = t2.typeID;
```

Comment: What is t1 and t2?

Comment: @ArkhamAngel, those are table alises for better redability